# undefined control sequence in latex

Tags: math-mode, errors

I snippet of my code is presented here.I do not understand why I'm getting the error undefined control sequence.I have also included the package `amsmath`.

```
\subsection{Logistic Regression}
\noindent $p_i=P(y_i=1)$ and $(x_i\in\mathbb{R})^d$. The binary responses are modelled using the following formulation $$\log{{p_{i}}\over{1-p_{i}}}={{\beta}}^{T}{\bf x}_{i}\qquad\text{or}\qquadp_{i}={{\exp({{\beta}}^{T}{\bf x}_{i})}\over{1+\exp({{\beta}}^{T}{\bf x}_{i})}}$$ where $\beta\in\mathbb{R}^d$ are some unknown regression coefficients often estimated using maximum likelihood.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use `\mathbb`, you also need to add `amssymb`:

[image]

In this instance, there seems to be no need for `\noindent` (unless you modified your sectional headings from the default). Note that I've completely rewritten the mathematical expression:

- Don't use `$$`...`$$` for your math display; rather use `\[`...`\]`. See [Why is `\[` … `\]` preferable to `$$` … `$$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5764);
- Don't use `{<num>}\over{<denom>}` for a fraction. Instead, use `\frac{<num>}{<denom>}`;
- Don't over-use braces; they *could* change the spacing of elements in the expression.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a polished version of your snippet:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb} % for \mathbb

\begin{document}

\subsection{Logistic Regression}

$p_i=P(y_i=1)$ and $(\mathbf{x}_i\in\mathbb{R}^d)$. The binary responses are 
modelled using the following formulation
\[
\log \frac{p_{i}}{1-p_{i}}=\beta^{T}\mathbf{x}_{i}
\qquad\text{or}\qquad
p_{i}=\frac{\exp(\beta^{T}\mathbf{x}_{i})}{1+\exp(\beta^{T}\mathbf{x}_{i})}
\]
where $\beta\in\mathbb{R}^d$ are some unknown regression coefficients often 
estimated using maximum likelihood.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: On the subject of polished looks: Are the parentheses needed in `$(\mathbf{x}_i\in\mathbb{R}^d)$`? I'm pretty sure they could/should be omitted.

Comment: @Mico I just put the exponent inside the bracket; it denotes a sequence of vectors, I guess.

Comment: I have to admit I've never seen it in text either. I've seen it is displayed math though, as a sort of comment on the variables

Comment: Thinking some more about the case at hand, it may be best to omit the subscript `i` from `\mathbf{x}` (I'm pretty sure we're just dealing with a d-element vector, rather than a sequence of vectors...) entirely and to write `\exp(\boldsymbol{\beta}^{T}\mathbf{x})`. After all, if we're going to use **bold** for one vector that shows up in an inner product, we might as well use it for both vectors...

Comment: @Mico In the formula `\mathbf{x}_{i}` is used and it *is* a d-dimensional vector. I would not enter into a debate about notation: every field is entitled having their own uses. Maybe coherence would require a boldface beta, usage might not. In any case, `\boldsymbol` is obsolete.